# Bound by confusion, needs clear explanation of post increment

Tags: c

guys i'm new at programming and i was surprised by the result of post increment value, now i'm bound by confusion after i found out and executed the code below, if for loop says
 1. initialize 
 2. check for condition if false terminate 
 3. incrementation. 
where does i++ happens? where does i value is equal to 1?

```
int main()
{
int i, j;

for (int i =0; i<1; i++)
{
    printf("Value of 'i' in inner loo[ is %d \n", i);




    j=i;
    printf("Value of 'i' in  outter loop is %d \n", j);
            // the value of j=i is equals to 0, why variable i didn't increment here?
}
    //note if i increments after the statement inside for loop runs, then why j=i is equals to 4226400? isn't spose to be 1 already? bcause the inside statements were done, then the incrementation process? where does i increments and become equals 1? 
    //if we have j=; and print j here
//j=i;  //the ouput of j in console is 4226400
//when does i++ executes? or when does it becomes to i=1?



return 0;
}
```

if Post increment uses the value and add 1? i'm lost... Please explain... thank you very much.

Comment: Your code talks about outer and inner loops, but there's only one loop there.

Comment: *3. incrementation. where does i++ happens?* incrementation **is** what `i++` means and it happens at the end of the `for` loop

Comment: Please read this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8(v=vs.71).aspx It explains exactly what you are confused on.

Comment: i'm sorry for the inner and outer loop, i was really confused by the thought of post increment.

Based on what i understand, it will only  increment or do any increment process whether it's post or pre only as soon as it re-enters the for loop statement again... right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but sometimes it's easier for beginners to understand if rewritten as a while loop:

```
 int i = 0;
 while (i < 1)
 {
     ...
     i++;  // equivalent to "i = i + 1", in this case.
 }
```

Comment: this is an interesting statement, i compared your while statement to my for loop statement, then therefore i++ executes  where it is placed, if it is for loop, it waits until it re-enters the for loop and does the increment, while inside while it does the increment after variable i is used in statement...

Answer (score 1):

Your loop declares new variable `i` and it shadows the `i` declared earlier in `main()`. So if you assign `i` to `j` outside of the loop, you are invoking undefined behaviour because `i` is not initialised in that context.

Comment: No, undefined, see Annex J.2 "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8)."

Comment: that is correct. Based on what i understand, it will only increment or do any increment process whether it's post or pre only as soon as it re-enters the for loop statement again... right?

Comment: @dreamlax My bad... Deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the first iteration, `i` is initialised to `0`. This is the "initialize" phase, as you called it.

The loop condition is then evaluated. The loop continues on a true value.

The loop body is then executed. If there's a `continue;` statement, that will cause execution to jump to the end of the loop, just before the `}`.

The increment operator is then evaluated for it's side-effects.

Hence, it is after the first iteration that `i` changes to `1`. `i` keeps the value `1` for the entirety of the second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a clash of variable names: `i` is declared before the loop, and also inside the loop.

The `i` that is declared in the `for` statement is the only one that will ever be 1. It will be one just after the body of the loop is executed.

Try setting a breakpoint and using the debugger to step through the loop whilst you watch the value of the variable (here's a video of what I mean by [stepping with the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee672313.aspx)).

To remove the ambiguitity of having two variables called `i` you could change the for loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) // remove the `int`
```

this will ensure that there is only one `i` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

A comment on @CarlNorum's answer which wouldn't look good as a comment:

The C Standard *defines*

```
for ( A; B; C ) STATEMENT
```

as meaning almost the same thing as

```
{
    A;
    while (B) {
        STATEMENT
        C;
    }
}
```

(where a `{}` block containing any number of statements is itself a kind of statement).  But a `continue;` statement within the `for` loop will jump to just before the next statement `C;`, not to the next test of expression `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<x; i++)
```

Is equivalent to

```
i=0;
while(i<x) {
    // body
    i = i + 1;
}
```